# Linq to XML. Selecting Multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

```
Dim MyQuery = From c In xdoc.Descendants() _
Where c.Attribute(OriginY) IsNot Nothing _
Order By Val(c.Attribute(OriginY).Value), Val(c.Attribute(OriginX).Value) _
Select c.Attribute(UniStr)
```

Right above you can see my First! linq attempt! And here comes my first question.

How can i select more than one column in a linq query in vb.net?

For example... **Select c.Attribute(UniStr) AND c.Attribute(OriginY)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a VB.NET person, but this should work (Providing your existing statement compiles):

```
Dim MyQuery = From c In xdoc.Descendants() _
Where c.Attribute(OriginY) IsNot Nothing _
Order By Val(c.Attribute(OriginY).Value), Val(c.Attribute(OriginX).Value) _
Select UniStr = c.Attribute(UniStr), OriginY = c.Attribute(OriginY)
```

You should read about [Projections in VB.NET and LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679939/what-options-do-i-have-for-linq-projections).